# How do I select all objects from a list that have no related objects in another list/model

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, ado.net-entity-data-model

Using linq,how do I select all Room objects *from a list of Room objects* for which no Booking objects exist in the Booking model (can check by foreign key)?

This is the list of the objects:

```
var rooms = (from m in db.Rooms
             where
             m.FK_HotelID == id
             select m).ToList();
```

This is the first model called Room:

```
public partial class Room
{
    public Room()
    {
        Bookings = new HashSet<Booking>();
    }
    public int RoomID { get; set; }
    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }
    public string RoomType { get; set; }
    // Foreign Key
    public int? FK_HotelID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    // Navigation Property
    public virtual Hotel Hotel { get; set; }
}
```

And a second model called Booking:

```
public partial class Booking
{
    public int BookingID { get; set; }
    public string BookingName { get; set; }
    public string BookingContact { get; set; }
    public DateTime BookingTime { get; set; }
    public string BookingStatus { get; set; }
    // Foreign Key
    public int? FK_RoomID { get; set; }
    // Navigation Property
    public virtual Room Room { get; set; }
}
```

I am a beginner to linq and all I can understand so far is how to select from a single model, although I can easily get the result using a SQL query with a left join.

P.S: I made the database first and generated the models using the *ADO.NET Entity Data Model Wizard* with *Code First from Database*. I also don't mind making any small changes to the database or model as long as I understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var unbookedRooms = db.Rooms.Where(r =>  r.FK_HotelID == id && !r.Bookings.Any()).ToList();
```

The idea is to use LINQ's `Any()` method on the child collection to exclude `Room` objects with non-empty `Booking` collections.

Comment: This does the trick. Not exactly what I was looking for, but it does provide a solution to my problem (list all Rooms that have never been booked).

Comment: On a side note, in the case of a reversed implementation where we include all `Room` objects with non-empty collections, i.e, `db.Rooms.Where(r => r.Bookings.Any()).ToList();` would it be easy to 
 also implement something of the following sorts as well: `Bookings.BookingStatus.Equals("Cancelled")`?

Comment: @salmanxk If I get your last comment correctly, you should be able to add the `BookingStatus` check to `Any()`, like this: `r =>  r.FK_HotelID == id && !r.Bookings.Any(b => b.BookingStatus.Equals("Cancelled"))` This would give you all rooms with at least one cancelled booking.

Comment: Exactly what I need! Although, you need to remove the `!`. Thanks for saving me from a day's migraine!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this;

```
var rooms = (from m in db.Rooms
             where
             m.FK_HotelID == id &&
             !m.Bookings.Any()
             select m).ToList();
```